# Beckhoff CP6606 communication

Tags: plc, twincat, bacnet

I have a client who wants to connect a CP6606 to a SCADA-server on a BACnet/IP network.
In short, this CP6606 is controlling an automatic waste collecting system, and now the customer wants to have all alarms and so on sent up to this SCADA-system which acts as a central operation unit.

Do we need a gateway, or can this be done from TwinCAT?
How to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I can help much, but I know that we can a vendor using TwinCAT via a Beckhoff PLC, and they seemed to need to write their own BACnet gateway (- but I'd probably recommend one that is already available & tested - be it one that might be provided via TwinCAT, or a piece of hardware that can already do it for you - if TwinCAT doesn't provided such an offering).

Comment: I've never actually worked with BACNet before but given that Beckhoff has an [entire module](https://www.beckhoff.com/en-us/products/automation/twincat/tfxxxx-twincat-3-functions/tf8xxx-tc3-industry-specific/tf8020.html) related to it, I can only assume that its not going to be too hard to implement, although they do reference the [EL6861](https://www.beckhoff.com/en-en/products/i-o/ethercat-terminals/el6xxx-communication/el6861.html) and [CX8191](https://www.beckhoff.com/en-en/products/ipc/embedded-pcs/cx8100-arm-cortex-a9/cx8191.html) as BACnet specific devices.

Comment: Thanx Steve, I'll look into it